# Pandas.str.replace Regex Application

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I am trying to do some data quality control and wanted to use Pandas.str.replace method to replace one string with another using a regular expression.  I am looking at reformatting a string that looks like

```
#'250 ED ENGLISH DR, BLDG #3 UNIT C,'
```

To something like this:

```
#'250 ED ENGLISH DR, #3C
```

I used the following but pandas is not recognizing that I'm trying to replace with regex:

```
df.Address=df.Address.str.replace(r'250 ENGLISH DR, BLDG #\d* UNIT \S[a-z]*', r'250 ENGLISH DR,' + r'(?<=250 ENGLISH DR, BLDG #)\d*' + r'\S{1,2}$', regex=True)
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to tweak this code to work?  The search string works brilliantly.

Comment: Use capturing groups in the pattern and backreferences in the replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Isn't that what my replace string is doing?

Comment: No, you are using a regex pattern in the replacement. Capture in the pattern the parts you need to keep with round brackets and in the replacement refer to them with `\n` where `n` is the group id. Numbering starts with `1` .

Comment: Try [`.replace(r'(250 ED ENGLISH DR, )BLDG (#\d+) UNIT ([a-zA-Z])\S*', r'\1\2\3', regex=True)`](https://regex101.com/r/NvDr2u/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are strictly trying to replace words 'BLDG' and 'UNIT', this would work.

```
df

    Address
0   250 ED ENGLISH DR, BLDG #3 UNIT C
```

Try

```
df.Address.str.replace('BLDG | UNIT ', '')
```

returns

```
0    250 ED ENGLISH DR, #3C
```

Comment: Suddenly I see that this is much simpler for this particular string.  Amazing how quickly your mind can overwork problems.  Out of curiosity, if I ever needed to use Regex to solve the problem, do you know the proper format?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
df.Address=df.Address.str.replace(r'250 ENGLISH DR, BLDG #(\d*) UNIT (\S[a-zA-Z]*)', r'250 ENGLISH DR, #\1\2')
```

Comment: @TylerRussell you can try this regex based solution

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a go on Monday when I get back to my office.